# Scrapy: How do I set an HTTP proxy to connect to HTTPS websites (HTTP works)?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using a middleware to enable a proxy like this:

I have this in settings.py

```
HTTP_PROXY='127.0.0.1:8080'
```

This is my middleware

```
from mybot.settings import HTTP_PROXY

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
      def process_request(self, request, spider):
          request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://%s' % HTTP_PROXY
```

It works fine for HTTP sites but not for HTTPS. What am I doing wrong? I have tested the proxy using curl and it can connect to HTTPS without a problem.

This is the error:

```
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable proxy for **http** and **https** both. For example in Windows, you can do it directly from shell like

```
set http_proxy = 127.0.0.1:8080
set https_proxy = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy 0.24 have some troubles with Twisted 15.0.0 so https throw proxy doesn't work. Uninstalling twisted and installing twisted 14.0.0 should work