# How to use a proxy with scrapy in a script based approach?

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy, browsermob-proxy

I can't seem to figure out how I would use a Browsermob-proxy with scrapy when using a script based approach. Has anyone come upon this use case before? Any help would be great I am using an approach as describer [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your script (I'm assuming you're using Bash) define your proxy such as:

```
http_proxy = 'http://user:password@server.com:3128'
```

right before you call the scrapy script. In scrapy you have to enable the Proxy Middleware.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094480/scrapy-how-do-i-set-an-http-proxy-to-connect-to-https-websites-http-works) and [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=proxy#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware) for more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm using a python script, it doesn't require you to create a project and so I'm not sure how I would include the middleware. You can see what I mean if you follow the link I posted in the question. Thanks again.EDIT: I changed the link to the correct one, apologies.

Comment: In your `CrawlerProces` instantiation you should be able to pass it as a settings, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess

Comment: In the settings there should be something like DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 100} you need to pass that setting somehow to the `CrawlerProcess`

Comment: If at all possible I think you would benefit from setting up a scrapy project and then running it with `scrapy crawl`

Comment: Perhaps in the future, currently working on more of a proof of concept and I need the proxy to create a har file for the requests